Error When Attempting to Import Dispatch from win32com.client
I'm trying to get PyXLL installed and am trying to take the preliminary step of calling into excel from python using win32 COM API.
From an Anaconda Prompt, with ipython, I type
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel Application')
But I get:
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
For reference, I am attempting to follow the instructions from the first two minutes of this video: https://youtu.be/ubqsRcCUcB4. I am using Windows 11.

I have verified that I am using a 64bit Excel and 64bit python.


I have repaired "Microsoft 365 - en-us" and uninstalled and reinstalled "Microsoft 365 (Office)" but this has not made a difference.


I have attempted to use EnsureDispatch as per this thread but this produced the same error



what about missing dot in Dispatch('Excel.Application')

That was it! I just couldn't see the dot in the video tutorial I was following. Thanks @Spatz.

@Spatz but it's still not working past the next step. Any more advice? I'm attempting to follow the next part of the video starting from here but what I see is different from what the guy shows. When he types xl, he gets <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance....". But i just see . And I'm not able to run the next line: https://youtu.be/ubqsRcCUcB4?t=66 without another error:  com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

Please [edit] your post and include a full code block of your issue without line snippets, external links, or screenshots of code. We don't see the next step.

As per the second issue I wrote about on 8/11 above in the comment, I realized that my issue had to do with the fact that I was assuming that the application would be referring to my currently open workbook (in the video, the presenter is able to simply begin editing an excel window he already has open) I'm not sure how he was able to do this, but I got mine to work by either creating a new workbook, making it visible and referring to it, or by opening a new workbook. To open a new wb:
'xl.Visible = True'
'wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()'
'ws = wb.Worksheets(1)'
ws.Range("A1").Value = 1
